# group homomorphism with complex composition

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let G be the group $(1,-1,i,-i)$ with multiplication of complex numbers as composition. Let H be the quotient group $Z/4Z$. Then the number of nontrivial group homomorphisms from H to G is=?

H will be ${0,1,2,3}$. but I am having trouble understanding the concept of homomorphism.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hints for the problem:

I'll follow your notation above of $H=\{0,1,2,3\}$, keeping in mind those are all modulo 4. I'll use $a,b\in H$ for arbitrary elements.

You mentioned that you're having trouble with what a homomorphism is. We can describe what it will do in this case. A homomorphism $\phi:\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z\to G$ is going to satisfy the following condition by definition:

$$
\phi(a + b)=\phi(a)\cdot\phi(b)
$$

(Addition is the operation in $H$, and multiplication in $G$.

You probably already know $\Bbb Z/4\Bbb Z$ is cyclic and generated by $1$.

A homomorphism from $H$ is completely determined by what it does with the generator $1$.

Since $1$ has order 4, it can be mapped to anything in $G$ whose order divides 4. If $1\mapsto 1\in G$, you have the trivial homomorphism.

What are the other possibilities?

Comment: 1->i, 1->-i, 1->-1. since i^4=1, -i^4=1, -1^2=1,1 being identity element.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT 1** $G$ and $H$ are isomorphic.

**HINT 2** What are the identities of $G$ and $H$? What must happen to the identity? What are the (normal) subgroups of $\mathbb{Z}/4$? They correspond to kernels of homomorphisms $G \to H$.